# Correspondance between modules over locations and modules over rings whose scalar multiplications form isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

This is part of Exercise 1.3.D in [Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf):

Let $A$ be a ring and $S$ be a multiplicative subset of $A$.

> **To show**: An $S^{-1}A$-module is the same thing as an $A$-module $M$ for which $s \times \_: M \to M$ is an isomorphism for all $s \in S$.

**My approach**:

- If we have an $S^{-1}A$-module $M$, we obtain an $A$-module $M$ by defining the scalar multiplication by $$a \times_{A} m := \frac{a}{1} \times_{S^{-1}A} m.$$
  Then $s \times_A \_$ is isomorphic because $$M \to M, \quad m \mapsto \frac{1}{s} \times_{S^{-1}A} m$$
  is its inverse.
- Conversely, if we have an $A$-module $N$ such that $s \times_A \_: N \to N$ is an isomorphism for all $s \in S$, then $N$ is an $S^{-1}A$-module by defining the scalar multiplication by $$ \frac{a}{s} \times_{S^{-1}A} n := a \times_A (s \times_A \_)^{-1}(n) .$$

I got confused by my construction and could not verify after certain attempts that these two maps are isomorphisms.

Could you please help me with this exercise? Thank you!

Comment: It seems you have not detected that the hypothesis $A$ is commutative and unital is crucial for how we define the localization.

Comment: In both the first and the second construction, the underlying set of $M$ is unchanged. So what you have to verify is the coincidence of scalar multiplication before and after. For instance, if you apply the second construction then the first, in the result $A$-module you have $a\times_A m=\frac{a}{1} \times_{S^{-1}A} m=a\times_A (1\times_{A} \_)^{-1} (m)=a\times_A m$.